Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:28), Build in NextJS
Estoy tratando de hacer un build en nextjs, para luego hacer un npm run start,
El error es que al hacer el build falla de la siguiente manera:
> project@0.1.0 build
> next build

 ⚠ Invalid next.config.js options detected:   
⚠     Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'loader'  
⚠ See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
   npx browserslist@latest
    --update-db   
    Why you should do it regularly: 
    https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating  
    ✓ Linting and checking validity of types     
    Failed to compile.
        

    ./.env Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:28) 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

y luego para al hacer npm run start, pasa lo siguiente y no logra servir la pagina:
    > project@0.1.0 start
> next start

 ⚠ Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
 ⚠     Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'loader'
 ⚠ See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspaces/folder/.next/BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/workspaces/folder/.next/BUILD_ID'
}


no eh encontrado la solución ni buscando en foros, ni con chatGPT,
muchas gracias de ante mano por su tiempo,
El contenido de mi next.config es el siguiente:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  output: "export",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;


agrega el contenido de tu next.config.js a la pregunta.

gracias, la acabó de hacer
